# PHP Syntax - Combine two PHP strings for a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to combine two PHP snippets so I can remove a certain Custom Post category from a Wordpress page.

Here's the main PHP snippet
`<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-21'); ?>`

And I want to include this in there so it only deletes the post categories from 
`( 'post_type' => 'portfolio' )`

Comment: You mean from those posts you need only ones with post_type = 'portfolio' - or ones except those?

Comment: I need to keep only ones that are "portfolio" but delete category 21 (notice the minus sign)

Answer (score 0):

I think this si what you're after:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-21&post_type=portfolio');?>
```

This will only show portfolios now, is that what you wanted? Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work at all, with my original code snippet I got a reaction, admittedly the wrong reaction. With this snippet nothing happens. The Portfolio already only show 'portfolio' post types however when I use the query_posts to magic away one category the whole lot is replaced by standard posts rather than the custom posts. So I thought by maybe telling wordpress to remove category 21 from only the custom post type 'portfolio' might work. Is there any other way this could be written?

Comment: I didn't realise 21 was portfolios. According the docs your `-21` is correct.. could you `var_dump($query_string)` please so I can see what that's doing?